# Why do I get this error in a RavenDB index query: The field 'CustomerId' is not indexed

Tags: indexing, ravendb

This is my index code:

```
public class InvoiceSummaryView
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public string DebtorName { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceSummaryIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CustomerInvoice>
{
    public InvoiceSummaryIndex()
    {

        Map = invoices => from invoice in invoices
                          select new { DueDate = invoice.DueDate, DebtorId = invoice.DebtorId, Amount = invoice.Amount };

        TransformResults = (database, results) =>
            from invoice in results
            let debtor = database.Load<Debtor>(invoice.DebtorId)
            let company = database.Load<Company>(debtor.CompanyId)              
            select new {
                DueDate = invoice.DueDate,
                CompanyAddress = Company.Address.ToString(),
                DebtorName = debtor.Contact.First + " " + debtor.Contact.Last,
                Amount = invoice.Amount,
                IsPaid = invoice.IsPaid,
                CustomerId = Company.CustomerId
            };

    }
}
```

And this is my query:

```
var query = from viewItem in session.Query<InvoiceSummaryView>("InvoiceSummaryIndex")
                        where viewItem.CustomerId == id
                        orderby viewItem.DueDate
                        select viewItem;
```

the error is:

"Error": "System.ArgumentException: The field 'CustomerId' is not indexed, 
   cannot query on fields that are not indexed   at ...

Answer (score 9):

Look at your index:

```
   select new { DueDate = invoice.DueDate, DebtorId = invoice.DebtorId, Amount = invoice.Amount };
```

The fields that you have indexed are DueDate, DebtorId and Amount, that is it.

If you'll it it like this:

```
   select new { DueDate = invoice.DueDate, DebtorId = invoice.DebtorId, Amount = invoice.Amount, invoice.CustomerId };
```

It will work

Comment: My initial impression was a flat table was being generated in the background for the final index result including the transformation. The way you describe it, sounds like that table is the index and the transform is done on the fly. Is that right?  So does that mean if I have a 4 level heirachy of entities and I was to query any of them, a child needs it's parents Id and it's parent's parent's Id etc?

Comment: And yes it creates the index but it returns no results, I looked at the index in Raven Studio and there's an index error converting string to float. The index shown in RS has compiled to cast the Amount: Amount = ((float)invoice.Amount). When I remove this cast from the Map and the Transform it works...

Comment: Idle, you can query only on the output of the map (or reduce, if it is there), TransformResults happen on the fly, yes.